# How to use local storage to access combined reducer values React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have been working on a personal project lately with react/redux/django and I had to use `combine reduces` modules because I have 2 reducers. My redux "blueprint" looks something like this:

```
authReducer: {
  IS_AUTHENTICATED:true
  AUTH_SUCCESS:true
  USERNAME:"Some User"
  TOKEN:"31d715af03390235d8e6bedd1c67e4853a365bd4"
}
roomReducer: {
  ACTIVEFRIEND: null
  ROOM: null
  ROOMS: [{}, {} ...]
}
```

also you should know that I have persisted the state using `local storage`. My problem is that I do not know how to access for example the `TOKEN` state using `local storage.get()` module. Keep in mind that I am using `combine reducers` from `react-redux`. Does anyone know the solution to my problem? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

Here are my reducers:

ROOM REDUCER

```
import backendTypes from "./Types";

const roomForm = {
  ACTIVEFRIEND: null,
  ROOMS: null,
  ROOM: null,
};

const roomReducer = (state = roomForm, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case backendTypes.GET_ROOMS_SUCCESS:
      state["ACTIVEFRIEND"] = null;
      state["ROOMS"] = action.allRooms;
      state["ROOM"] = null;

      return state;
    case backendTypes.GET_ROOM_SUCCESS:
      state["ACTIVEFRIEND"] = action.activeFriend;
      state["ROOMS"] = localStorage.getItem("ROOMS");
      state["ROOM"] = action.activeRoom;

      return state;
    case backendTypes.GET_ROOMS_FAIL:
      state["ACTIVEFRIEND"] = null;
      state["ROOMS"] = null;
      state["ROOM"] = null;

      return state;
    case backendTypes.GET_ROOM_FAIL:
      state["ACTIVEFRIEND"] = null;
      state["ROOMS"] = localStorage.getItem("ROOMS");
      state["ROOM"] = null;

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default roomReducer;
```

AUTH REDUCER

```
import authTypes from "./Types";

const authForm = {
  IS_AUTHENTICATED: false,
  AUTH_SUCCESS: false,
  USERNAME: "AnonymousUser",
  TOKEN: null,
};

const authReducer = (state = authForm, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case authTypes.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = true;
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = true;
      state["USERNAME"] = action.username;
      state["TOKEN"] = action.token;

      return state;
    case authTypes.SIGN_IN_FAIL:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = false;
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = false;
      state["USERNAME"] = "AnonymousUser";
      state["TOKEN"] = null;

      return state;
    case authTypes.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = true;
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = true;
      state["USERNAME"] = action.username;
      state["TOKEN"] = action.token;

      return state;
    case authTypes.SIGN_UP_FAIL:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = false;
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = false;
      state["USERNAME"] = "AnonymousUser";
      state["TOKEN"] = null;

      return state;
    case authTypes.SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = false;
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = false;
      state["USERNAME"] = "AnonymousUser";
      state["TOKEN"] = null;

      return state;
    case authTypes.SIGN_OUT_FAIL:
      state["IS_AUTHENTICATED"] = localStorage.getItem("IS_AUTHENTICATED");
      state["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = false;
      state["USERNAME"] = localStorage.getItem("USERNAME");
      state["TOKEN"] = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

COMBINED REDUCER

```
import authReducer from "./Auth/Reducer";
import roomReducer from "./Backend/Reducer";

import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  roomReducer,
});

export default reducer;
```

index.js

```
...
function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
  try {
    const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("persistantState", serialisedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const serialisedState = localStorage.getItem("persistantState");
    if (serialisedState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
    return undefined;
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  loadFromLocalStorage(),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value from the local storage directly in your initial state.

```
initialState = {
 token: localStorage.get('token'),
 something: localStorage.get('something'),
}
```

Comment: can u educate me on initial state a bit more?

Comment: can you show your reducer ? don't you have initial state in your reducer?

Comment: just did that : ), in the edit section of the question

Comment: const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  loadFromLocalStorage, // instead of loadFromLocalStorage()
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

Comment: Now its telling me I am passing several store enhancers and I should compose them

Comment: `compose(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())`